# Is this a valid makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a makefile to build my C++ program. Here is what I want it to do.
1. Take main.cpp, and cipher.cpp, and compile them into .o's
2. Link the two .o's together twice, one into an executable called cipher, the other decipher.

The reason I have two executables is that the main.cpp checks which executable you are using by checking argv, and then does cipher or decipher accordingly.

The makefile I have written is here: [Makefile on Pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/tWiezRzb)

Is this a valid/good makefile? I want to know if this will work well and if there are any better ways to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's certainly valid.  If the two executables are truly intended to be identical, you can save some work by making one a copy or hard link of the other, instead of compiling the same code twice:

```
cipher: main.o cipher.o
        $(GCC) $(FLAGS) main.o cipher.o -o $@

decipher: cipher
        ln -f $< $@
```

Note that I've used the [automatic variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) `$<` and `$@` to refer to the names of the first prerequisite and the name of the target respectively.  They're not strictly necessary here, but I think they're good practice, since they really come in handy when you start specifying more complex pattern-matching rules.

Comment: You could also use `$^` in the `cipher` rule.